# what is the error using OOPS with PDO

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am learning **OOPS** concept and also using [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) , but really stuck in very basic problem, please look into my code and tell me what i am doing wrong and how to optimize this code.

###class.db.php

```
class DB
{
    public $dbh;
    private $qry;
    
    public function __construct($user ='root',$pass = '')
    {
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=parixan',$user,$pass);
            $this->dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); 
            echo "connected";
        } catch(Exception $e){
            die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
        }       
    }
}
```

###class.user.php

```
class User
{
    public $db;
    protected $_table ='tbl_user';
    public function __construct($dbh)
    {
        $this->db = $dbh;       
    }
    public function getUserDetails($id) //line #10
    {
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM $this->_table WHERE id = :userID LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($qry); //line #13
        $stmt->bindParam(':userID',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);  
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<pre>";print_r($row);
        }
    }

    }
    
}
```

###user.php

```
include_once('class.user.php');
include_once('class.db.php');
$dbh = new DB();
$obj_user = new User($dbh);
$obj_user ->getUserDetails(1);
```

on running `user.php` I got this one

> connected Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::prepare() in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\oops\class.user.php on line 13

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `User` object, `$this->db` is a reference to an object of the `DB` class. This class does not implement a `prepare` method, so there is none available when you attempt to call it with `$stmt = $this->db->prepare($qry);`.

If you persist with your current class design, you need to create such a function:

```
public function prepare($qry) {
    return $this->dbh->prepare($qry);
}
```

This means you will now have a `PDOStatement` object, on which you can call `bindParam` and `execute`.

Comment: i really dont want to persist current class design. Can u suggest what modifications needed for standard code.

Comment: i am little bit confused that is it necessary to send `$dbh` to each new class i initiate?? like this `$obj_user = new User($dbh);` or is there other way around?

Comment: Well, I'd forget about using your own DB class and just use a PDO object: that should be quite suitable for your needs.

Comment: means in each class's constructor,  i need to crate PDO object??

Comment: @diEcho Any object that needs database access will need to be provided with the database object. The nicest way to do this is to pass it in at the creation of the object. Yours is the simplest approach: in the long run you may want to look at the dependency injection pattern, which is probably the most sustainable approach to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. :)